# Google passkey not working

Tags: samsung, google-account, google-play-services, passkey

I have the passkey enabled for my Google account and, so, for my Samsung device.

The problem is that if I try to log in through MS Edge, it displays the QR code, I scan the code (`FIDO:/XXXXXXX`) but on the device, all is blocked (in fact I can see that Google Play services is opened, but nothing happens).

Does anyone know if the problem is on my side or what?

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following workaround that could possibly fix your concern:

- Clear browser cache and cookies
- Disable browser extensions
- Update browser and Google Passkey app
- Check the internet connection
- Disable VPN or proxy
- Use incognito mode
- Reset Google Passkey

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. While we appreciate everyone's contribution, looks like you're affiliated with the website. While it's okay to refer to an affiliated website, take note that *explicit disclosure is required on the post itself*. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: That said, some of your points don't make sense, such as the "Google Passkey app" (there's no such app). Without additional references, this answer (particularly the original article) is suspected to be generated using AI, which can and does [hallucinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination_(artificial_intelligence)).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Its definitely ftom chatgpt.